# Display column name in Datagrid C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code that creates a `dataview` for a `datagrid`:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        dataGrid1.TableStyles.Clear();
        tableStyle.MappingName = dt.TableName;
        DataGridTextBoxColumn columnStyle;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(" Description - Code ", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Found", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Expected", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns[0].MaxLength = 240;
        DataColumn dataColumn = dt.Columns[0];
        dataColumn.Caption=" Description - Code ";
        columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        columnStyle.Width = 210;
        columnStyle.MappingName = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(columnStyle);
        DataGridTextBoxColumn cs;
        cs = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        cs.MappingName = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
        cs.Width = 35;
        DataGridTextBoxColumn cs2;
        cs2 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();           
        cs2.MappingName = dt.Columns[2].ColumnName;
        cs2.Width = 35;
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(cs);
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(cs2);
        dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);
        for (int j = 0; j < distL.Count; j++)          
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = distL[j];
            dr[1] = a[j] + 1;
            dr[2] = QuantExp[j];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
         }
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt).Table.DefaultView;
        dv.BeginInit();          
        dataGrid1.RowHeadersVisible = true;          
        return dv;
```

My problem is that when the datagrid is produced, the names of each column are not visible in the grid. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Do you have a special reason for doing this in code instead of the designer?

Comment: Yes the values of distL[j], a[j] and QuantExp arent fixed and known to me from the start, but only after the program runs...

Comment: I think the datagrid has something called Datagridcolumn. You can alternatively use the Datagridview class.

Comment: Then use `DataGridView` instead, it automatically generates the columns when you bind a data source to it. In your case this seems to be desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it...

In order to view the column name you must put instead of "columnStyle.MappingName"  "columnStyle.HeaderText"